# Properties of solutions of ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

I am stuck with an exercise.

Let $ f = f(t, y) $ be a continuous function such that $ \partial f / \partial y $ is continuous in all points $ (t, y) $. Say what you can about existence of global solution, sign and other estimations for the ODE $ dy/dt = f(t,y) $ under the following hypothesis:

**a)** Initial condition $ y(0) = 1 $, and $ y_1(t) = 3 $ is a solution for all $ t $.

**b)** Initial condition $ y(0) = 0 $, and $ y_1(t) =-1 $ and $ y_2(t) = e - t² + 1 $ are solutions for all $ t $.

**c)** Initial condition $ y(0) = 1 $, and $ y_1(t) = t + 2 $ and $ y_2(t) = -t² $ are solutions for all $ t $.

I know any initial condition $ y(t_0) = y_0 $ gives an unique solution to the problem, because $ f $ and its derivative $ \partial f / \partial y $ are continuous on the entire plane. My question is, what more can I say?

I don't expect a complete solution of the exercise, only some hints about how to go on.

Comment: I don't get it . Are you saying in **a)** that $y_1\equiv 3$ is a solution that satisfies $y_1(0)=1$ ?

Comment: No. In **a)** the exercise gives you an initial condition, and also gives you more information: the function $ y_1 = 3 $ is a solution of the ODE. So, you should say something about the solutions of the ODE with the given initial condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a scalar ODE with the given assumptions, if $y_1(0)<y_2(0)$ then $y_1(t)<y_2(t)$ for all times where both solutions exist, simply because solutions can not cross under the uniqueness condition.

Furthermore, if a solution is bounded to both sides, then its maximal domain is at least as large as the intersection of the domains of the bounds.